# Time value as output

Tags: informatica-powercenter

For few columns from the source i.e .csv file, we are having values like `1:52:00`, `14:45:00`.

I am supposed to load to the Oracle table.

Which data type should I choose in Target as well as source?
Should i be doing any thing in the expression transformation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Target table already exist, Its still in development mode we can change the datatype.

Just wanted to check wat datatype should i choose in Target.

What logic should i write in the Expression transformation.

Iam trying with the  logic TO_DATE(ETA,'HH24:MI:SS'),  it says its not valid.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLLDR to load the data into database with the format described as in the link

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

ie.'HH24:MI:SS'

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support time-only values, it supports dates (with a time component).
You have a few options:

1. Store the value as a string, perhaps providing a leading zero for
   the hour.
2. Store the value as the number of seconds (or minutes) past midnight.
3. Store the value as the time component of some arbitrarily defined date, for
   example `0001-JAN-01 01:52:00` and `0001-Jan-01 14:45:00`.  Tell your report writers to ignore the date portion of the value.

Your source datatype will be `string(8)`.  Use `LPAD` to add leading zeroes.